# Combine multiple CSV files into one DolphinDB table

Tags: database, loops, dolphindb

I have 5 CSV files which I want to combine into one DolphinDB table. The size of these csv files are approximated 2 gb, it might get so slow to do with `for loop`.

Can I do a load of these files without `for loop`?
Please let me know if there is any better new way in DolphinDB to load all of the files at once?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 loop(loadText, fileDir + "/" + files(fileDir).filename).unionAll(false)
```

**ploop** is the corresponding parallel version of loop.